# Associativity of Wreath Product Group Action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions, wreath-product

Given two groups $H$ and $K$ such that $K$  acts on a non-empty set $\Delta$, we can compute the wreath product as $G = H \wr{_\Delta} K := Fun(\Delta,H)\rtimes K$. Now, suppose that $H$ acts on the set $\Gamma$. Following Dixon and Mortimer, and [Primitive Wreath Product action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818306/primitive-wreath-product-action), the product action of $G$ on $Fun(\Delta,\Gamma$) is defined as:
$\forall (f,k) \in G = Fun(\Delta, H) \rtimes K$, $\forall \phi \in Fun(\Delta,\Gamma)$
$$\phi(f,k)(\delta):=f(k^{−1}\delta ) \cdot \phi(k^{−1} \delta)$$

I am having a hard time showing this associative. This is my attempt:
$$
\begin{align}
(f,k_1)((g,k_2) \cdot \phi(\delta)) &&= (f,k_1)(g(k_2^{-1}\delta) \cdot \phi(k_2^{-1}\delta) 
\end{align}
$$

On the other hand, by multiplication in the wreath product $(f,k_1)\cdot(g, k_2) = (f(k^{-1}g, k_1k_2)$, where the action of $k^{-1}g$ is the action of K the function g such that kg = $g(k^{-1}\delta)$
So,
$$
\begin{align}
(fg, k_1k_2) \cdot \phi(\delta) &= 
fg(k_2k_1^{-1}k_1 \delta) \cdot \phi(k_2^{-1}k_1^{-1}\delta) \\ &= fg(k_2\delta)\phi(k_2^{-1}k_1^{-1}\delta)
\end{align}
$$

Clearly, I have gone wrong somewhere, but I don't know where. Either the action or group multiplication is wrong.

Comment: There are obviously lots of errors/typos in what you write. In the first computation, first line, why do you have all $k_1$s, and no $k_2$s, but you have $k_2$s in the second line? In the second calculation, first line, why do you have $k_2k_1^{-1}$ first, rather than $k_2^{-1}k_1^{-1}$ as you do immediately after? And your parentheses are unbalanced in the first calculation.

Comment: Also, your calculations are clearly confused. You say that $(f,k_1)(g,k_2) = (fg(k_1\delta),k_1k_2)$, which cannot be parsed: $\delta$ does not occur on the right hand side, and also $g(k_1\delta)\in H$ whereas $f$ is a function $f\colon \Delta\to H$; you cannot multiply the function $f$ by the element $g(k_1\delta)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've fixed the typos. The term $ fg(k_1\delta)$ is supposed to be the multiplication of $f$ ad $g$

Comment: You are still misunderstanding what your  objects are.  For example, the element $(g,k_1)$ acts on functions, not on elements. So you can't compute $(g,k_1)(\phi(\delta))$; you should be computing $\Bigl( (g,k_1)(\phi)\Bigr)$ **at** $\delta$. So your second displayed equation (which still has unbalanced parentheses) still cannot be parsed.This kind of verification requires you to be very careful about the objects you are dealing with, and you are not being careful. And $fg(k_1\delta)$ **still** makes no sense, no matter what it was *supposed* to be.